# ExecuteNonQuery not deleting when it has to delete large number of rows

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I would like to go over all the tables in the database and delete all rows with particular id. When the number of rows are smaller, it works fine.

in a particular table the number of rows is 900000 and this doesn't work anymore.

Here is my current code:

```
Using connection = New MySqlConnection(connectionString)
    Try
        connection.open()
        If listOfTables.Count > 0 Then
            For Each table As String In listOfTables
                Dim sqlc As String = "DELETE FROM " & dbConnection.DbName & "." & table & " WHERE id=" & cNumber& ";"

                Dim command3 As New MySqlCommand(sqlc , connection)
                command3.ExecuteNonQuery()
                command3.Dispose()
            Next
            connection.close()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Using
```

Comment: Are you getting an exception?  Also, your `Connection.Open()` is outside the `If` but your `Connection.Close()` is inside the `If`.

Comment: Add some `Debug.WriteLine(..)` Statements, add a finally block to close your connection, and print out any exceptions which may occur. Afterwards let us know what you found out.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting 900000 rows in once from table is not a good idea. Why don't you write a stored procedure in MYSQL which do your work. You can Try creating stored procedure which deletes records in chunks of 1000 rows in the loop and do not stop until all the rows deleted.

Try out following pseudo code:

```
 @counter = 0
 LOOP
    DELETE FROM Table_name
      WHERE id BETWEEN @counter  AND @counter +1000
        AND "Your conditions"
    SET @counter  = @counter  + 1000
    sleep 2  -- Take a sleep before next
  UNTIL end of table
```

It uses the id column as Primary-key with auto increment

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the above answer about the stored procedure loop.
However, you never mentioned if you are getting an error/exception or if it just times out.
Perhaps you should:

```
Catch ex As Exception
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
     connection.close()
End Try
```